# Test Jest para componente funcional en React con llamada a API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, test, jest

He creado un componente en React, que renderiza su contenido a partir de los datos obtenidos en una API. Cuando los datos llegan, estos los introduzco en el estado local del componente.

A partir de aquí el componente hace uso de ese estado, y utiliza los datos para pintar una lista.

```
const UserList = ({ type }) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [usersByType, setUsersByType] = useState([]);
  let update = useSelector((state) => state.update);

  const getMaxFiveUsers = (users) => {
    return users[type].slice(0, 5);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsersByType().then((users) => {
      setUsers(users);
      setUsersByType(getMaxFiveUsers(users));
    });
  }, [update]);

  return (
    <div className={usersByType.length ? "userlist" : "hidden"}>
      <ul>
        {usersByType.map((user, i) => {
          return (
            <li className="userlist__item" key={i}>
              <UserCell username={user} userType={type} users={users} />
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserList;
```

El problema está que quiero testear este componente con Jest, y al renderizarlo, el componente no tiene valores en su estado y por tanto me devuelve una lista vacía.

¿Se puede setear su estado al iniciar el test para introducir unos usuarios de prueba y así renderizar el listado?

Comment: Imagino que getUsersByType hace un Fetch al server. Deberías ser poder capaz de mockear esa dependencia en tiempo de test con jest para que devuelva una promesa con datos fake.

Comment: Así es @JoseHermosillaRodrigo pero no sé como se haría. Sabes de algún ejemplo o documentación con el que pueda aplicar ese mockeo de datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu caso te interesa mockear la dependencia que trae los datos del servidor: `getUsersByType`. Para ello puedes utilizar `jest.mock` y [mockear el módulo](https://jestjs.io/es-ES/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules) (Suponiendo que la función a mockear sea el `default export`):

```
import getUserByType from '../path/a/getUsersByType.js';

jest.mock('../path/a/getUsersByType.js');

test('should render user list', () => {
  const list = [{name: 'Bob'}];
  getUsersByType.mockResolvedValue(Promise.resolve(list));
  
  
  // TODO: Renderiza el componente y realiza los asserts
  // ...
});
```

En el caso de que no sea el `default export` hay [varias formas](https://www.chakshunyu.com/blog/how-to-mock-only-one-function-from-a-module-in-jest/) de hacerlo, una de ellas sería con `jest#spyOn`:

```
import api from '../path/a/api.js';

// En el test...
jest.spyOn(api, 'getUsersByType').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(list));
```

Comment: ¡Interesante! En mi caso no es el default export. El fichero está conformado por constantes exportadas, en este caso la de getUserByType es una de ellas

Comment: He editado la respuesta incluyendo ese caso.

Comment: Efectivamente, esta aportación me ha servido de mucho. ¡Gracias y un saludo!